# Pagination padding problem

Tags: playa, pagination

I have problem with the page_padding parameters in paginate.. there's my code

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="serie_emission"  url_title="{segment_2}" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data" limit="1" status="open|OffMEO"}
    {exp:playa:parents channel="episode_emission" limit="6" var_prefix="ep" paginate="bottom" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data"}
        <div class="bloc1_element_listeVideo">
            <a href="{path='/emission/{url_title}/{ep:url_title}'}">
                <span class="titreElement_Video">TEXT</span>
                <span class="MeoElement_Video">{ep:entry_date format="%j %F %Y"}</span>
            </a>          
        </div>
        {ep:paginate}
            {pagination_links   page_padding="5"} {!--  page_padding NOT WORKING --}
                <div class="paginationEmission">
                {first_page}
                        <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first"><<</a>
                {/first_page}
                {previous_page}
                        <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous"><</a>
                    {/previous_page}
                    {page}
                        <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number}                      {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a>
                    {/page}
                    {next_page}
                        <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">></a>
                    {/next_page}
                    {last_page}
                        <a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">>></a>
                    {/last_page} 
                </div>
            {/pagination_links}
        {/ep:paginate}          
    {/exp:playa:parents} 
</div> <!-- # bloc1_listeVideo -->
</div> <!-- #mobContent -->
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Even if i have 10pages,, i only see 2 page on each 'side'..

Thanks

Comment: What version of EE are you running?

Comment: EE 2.7.3, PLaya 4.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `page_padding` parameter was added in EE 2.8, so you'll need to upgrade in order to use it.